# remove rows which total 0 from large R data frame, where first and last columns are not numeric

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe and need to remove a few rows from it as `rowSums` shows these to be 0 and thus impacting my downstream analysis. I've seen that you can do `df[rowSums(df[, -1])>0, ]` to achieve this, but I get an error stating that "x must be numeric" as both the first and last columns are not numeric. Any ideas of how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to remove the first and last columns by indexing

```
i1 <- sapply(df, is.numeric) # // get a logical index for numeric columns
df[rowSums(df[i1]) > 0,]
```

Comment: brilliant, thanks!